# how to parse this format of xml?

Tags: android, xml, sax

I tried to use SAX in parsing the following format:

```
<rootxml>
<url src="Jessica%20Alba/46459359.jpg"/>
<url src="Jessica%20Alba/97830837.jpg"/>
<url src="Jessica%20Alba/12062083.jpg"/>
<url src="Jessica%20Alba/10484795.jpg"/>
</rootxml>
```

by using this code

```
if(localName.equals("url")){

            String source = attributes.getValue("src");
            urls.add(source);
            info.setSRC(source);

        }
```

But I've no success...

Comment: There is no ¨data¨ attribute, so why would you expect something from it?

Comment: have you at-least opened and seen the links shown in this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089291/how-to-parse-xml-in-android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think This `code` is help to you
Replace this instead of above code for `XML Parser`

```
if(localName.equals("url")){

            String source = atts.getValue(0);
            urls.add(source);
            info.setSRC(source);

        }
```

Hope this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(localName.equals("url")){

            String source = attributes.getValue("src");
            urls.add(source);
            info.setSRC(source);

        }
```

Hope this should work for you. There is no data attribute and you are getting data attribute.